# Checking native dependency library is installed in Python setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a python application that requires a specific C library to be installed on the machine to build properly (usually installed via `sudo yum install xxx` or `sudo apt-get install xxx`).

Is there a way to verify that those packages are already installed from within setuptools and if not, prompt the user to install them?

Comment: In a cross-platform way?

Comment: please, please, please do not do that.

Comment: RHEL/Debian if possible, Windows might be too complicated.

Comment: @iced: Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: you'll never make it right. even somewhat close to "right". it's just not worth it. all you can and should do is explained https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html here

Comment: you can check that the required headers are available in your setup.py. https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/setup.py The psycopg2 package depends on postgres headers, you can check out its setup.py file (linked above) to see how it verifies existence, and how to gracefully fail, if some packages are unavailable.

Comment: You can see how PyYaml does it here: https://bitbucket.org/xi/pyyaml/src/ddf211a41bb231c365fece5599b7e484e6dc33fc/setup.py?at=default . In their case, the C lib is optional and it installs without support if the C lib is not available. Might give you some ideas.